# How to upload ChosenPhoto to a server?

Tags: windows-phone-8, service

if image added to project(build action=Content):

```
cameraCaptureTask = new CameraCaptureTask();
cameraCaptureTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(async (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        var bytes = Converter("myimage.png");
        Sender(bytes, Path.GetFileName(e.OriginalFileName));

    }

});
```

...

```
public byte[] Converter(string path)
        {
            byte[] image = null;
            try
            {
                Stream stream = File.OpenRead(path);
                image = new byte[stream.Length];
                int count = 0;
                while (count < stream.Length)
                {
                    image[count++] = Convert.ToByte(stream.ReadByte());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return image;
        }
```

it's ok.
when I try send ChosenPhoto:

```
var bytes = Converter(e.ChosenPhoto);
```

...
    private byte[] Converter(Stream stream)
            {
                byte[] image = null;
                try
                {
                    image = new byte[stream.Length];
                    int count = 0;
                    while (count < stream.Length)
                    {
                        image[count++] = Convert.ToByte(stream.ReadByte());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                return image;
            }

Nothing happens (the server does not get image). how I can fix this?

Comment: You forgot the most important code where you try to send it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fiddler to check this is client or server side error.